# Adding Menu item into NavigationView without create menu.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, navigationview

I get data from the server , Is there a way to add items to a NavigationView without create a folder menu and puts items in the xml file ?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="********">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ContentFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/DrawerNavView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        drawerNavView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.DrawerNavView);
```

The code above crash the app.

Comment: Why don't you want create menu folder and xml file ? Please explain.

Comment: Because my menu will be changed , the data for the menu come from the database